# Import dropping for no particular reason

Tags: tropico-4

I'm playing the Import/export campain mission in Tropico 4, and I've noticed from 1962, my import volume is dropping. And the export volume is also dropping since I export only industrialized/transformed products after importing them.

Why is that and what can I do to get back my export revenues ?

I have checked every indicators : all my factions are around 100%, my 2 docks are up and running, my relationships with nations is mostly above 90% and always above 50%, and of course all imports are authorized (coffee for box of coffees and tobacco for cigars).

Is it just a bug ?

[image]

Note : a few moments later (~= 3 ingame years), imports and exports are back for no particular reason and no action from me. I like Tropico but I don't like this kind of random behaviors, can "drought" be responsible for this ?

[image]

Comment: During this slump, did you check your factories at all? Were their imports empty, or their exports full at any point?

Comment: The numbers of the factories where conform to the global numbers : no import (but authorized) and low export. I think it may just be a game trigger during the campain/tutorial.